# How to put special permissions to people in a bot? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So basically, I want to give certain commands to me and my friend, the bot owners. Previously, I did this to give rights/commands to MYSELF only:

```
  var owner = ("487218875138572298")

  if (msg.startsWith (prefix + "example")){
    if (message.author.id === owner){
    message.channel.send("This is an example")
      } else
    return;
  }
```

But now, I want to put my ID, and my friend's ID. I tried some probably really dumb things as I am new to coding, so help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do something like this in Javascript is as follows:

```js
var privileged = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];

if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "example")){
  if (privileged.includes(message.author.id)){
     message.channel.send("This is an example");
  } else return;
}
```

The user IDs that should have the privilege are in the `privileged` array, and `privileged.includes(message.author.id)` checks if the author's ID matches any of those.

Comment: It says that privileged.contains is not a function... I literally pasted the code and changed abcdefghi with IDs

Comment: Sorry, meant `includes`. Try again.